3 Girlfriends ignore their blonde friend after her newborn dies
The movie is about 4 girlfriends, 2 of whom are pregnant. They give birth, but one baby dies the next day. At first the girls support their friend, but then gradually start excluding her from their meetings, chats, baptizing of the baby etc. She was trying to get over her grief and really suffered from her friends' actions. In the end she got pregnant again, and suddenly she got all the attention, but the friendship seemed ruined.
Country: U.S.
Year: Early 2000s 
Additional details: The main character is a young woman with short fair hair.

Approximate year of release? Country\language? Possible actors? Was it a TV movie?

Its a US movie, the release year is early 2000~, the main character is a young woman with short fair hair, thats all i can remember...

Sounds like you're looking for Everything Put Together from 2000.

Angie (Radha Mitchell) is pregnant and is having [a] course with her friends, Barbie (Megan Mullally) and Judith (Catherine Lloyd Burns), who are also pregnant. Her husband is in love with her, and they both are preparing carefully the baby's room. [...] On the delivery, Angie has a beautiful and perfect son, Gabriel, who dies less than twenty-four hours after of `sudden death', without any apparent reason. This is the beginning of Angie´s journey to hell, with the loss not only of the baby, but also of her shallow friendships.

Mitchell has short blonde hair and her friend doesn't invite her to her child's baptism at some point. Here's the trailer:




OOOOH yes thats it! thanks a lot!!!!
